# Is it possible for a keyboard key to not generate a scancode?

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint, scancodes

I have recently moved to Linux full time, and am enjoying the learning curve. However, one particular thing has me stumped big time: Some of the Fn key combinations on my laptop are not working, spec. Volume up/down, Mute, etc. Combinations that are working include WLAN, Sleep, Video cycle, numeric pad, etc. I can rule out a H/W fault, since the keys worked perfectly fine on Windows 7 (although only when the hotkeys software by the laptop maker was installed).

I have scoured the net for possible explanations, and have come across the concepts of **scancode** (HW dependent), **keycode** and **keysym**. I think I understand the basics, and have found that console and X have their own mappings, and need to be remapped separately. The console uses the kernel mapping of scancodes to keycodes, but X for some reason has its own mapping. For my part, I have tried:

1. Set the boot parameter `atkbd.softraw=0`
2. Switched to console mode by Ctrl + Alt + F1
3. Used `showkey --scancodes`. Unfortunately, the keys that I am trying to get working do not show any scancode output
4. Used `dmesg` to see if any Unknown key pressed events have occured, but none found.
5. In my desperation, tried `acpi_listen` to see if the keys were actually firing any acpi events instead, only sleep and video cycle keys do, others do not output anything

At this point, I thought maybe I should try getting scancodes from the X environment itself, using `xev`, but no luck.

I have come here as a last resort only. I hope somebody has a good explanation as to why some of the function key combinations are not generating any output in the tools I have tried above. If it helps, I am using Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon, and the laptop is made by HCL. `evtest` shows the keyboard device to be AT Translated Set 2 keyboard. If more info is needed, I would be happy to oblige. Thanks.

EDIT: No relevant BIOS setting is available.

Confession: All my knowledge on this is based on what I have been reading up on Arch wiki, Ubuntu wiki, a whole lot of forum posts and other websites. So, if I am technically wrong about something, please bear with me, and correct me. I love learning this stuff :)

Comment: What is `xev` telling you? Did you try *without* `atkbd.softraw`

Comment: First, I was trying without `atkbd.softraw`, it didn't work either. `xev` shows the relevant output for everything but the function key combinations I mentioned. Even, the working function key combinations like the wireless, etc. do not show any output in `xev`, `showkey` or `evtest`. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: On my laptop, it is handled by BIOS / ACPI / UEFI i.e. below the kernel

Comment: Yes, but the BIOS still passes the scancode to kernel? If so, I could in theory get them by using some tool, no?

Comment: Maybe it could be some BIOS setting

Comment: Came here because I have the same problem. @rahul1210: how did it go? Did you find a solution? Care to share your experience?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some keys on USB keyboards might not generate a scan code sent via the USB HID keyboard protocol but instead use a different USB protocol to communicate some user input. From what you've described, that's most likely what's happening here. You may be able to use programs from the `evmu-tools` package (that's the Debian name) or the older `evtest` program to find out more about what your particular device is doing for things that appear not to be sending keyboard scan codes.

(It also seems, from reading The Unix & Linux SE question ["How to get all my keys to send keycodes"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/130656/10489) that there's something going on with keycodes above 255, but I'm not clear on what's going on there.)

There's also an error in your understanding of the layering:

> The console uses the kernel mapping of scancodes to keycodes, but X for some reason has its own mapping.

This is not quite correct. The kernel maps scan codes to *keycodes* between 1 and 255; you can see this mapping with `getkeycodes(8)` and change it with `setkeycodes(8)` or udev. (The Arch Wiki page [Map scancodes to keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) has many details on this.) Not all scan codes have a mapping to a keycode; receipt of a scan code with no translation entry are what you would have seen in `dmesg`, had there been any.

Only after the scan code is converted to a kernel keycode do the console and X11 have access to these; each has its own mechanism to translate keycodes to actions.

Note that the console program `showkey -s` does not show actual scan codes that have been received; it reads keycodes (as shown by `showkey -k`) and translates those back into scan codes using the kernel table shown by `getkeycodes(8)`.

Answer (score -1):

It might depend upon the X11 [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager). You should try using [xev(1)](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) to understand what is going on.

Maybe using some other desktop suite like `xfce` or `lxde` or `gnome`, `kde`, `icewm` might help

Maybe configuring explicitly your keyboard (e.g. in `/etc/Xorg.conf`...) might help.

Comment: I hope not, could you please elaborate how it might influence the situation. If I understand correcty, the scancode to keycode mapping depends on the X server implementation. Assuming a less than ideal mapping, how could it completely hide the scancode events? Surely, there must be some way to get these scancodes, right?